# How to run an executable on all files in ONLY ONE directory ( no subfolder)

Tags: loops, batch-file, directory, subdirectory

I have a line in a batch file that loops through all folders and runs an executable for all *sourcefiles* that are contained in each folder:

```
for /r %%v in (*.pdf) do  (%exepath% "%%v" -w  )
```

- %exepath% is the path to my executable
- %sourcepath% is the path to where all my *sourcefiles* are located
- -w is a command line option used with my executable.

**Now I want to run my executable in this specific folder only** ( no subfolders)
what would be the command? I tried this:

```
cd %sourcepath%
for %f in (*.pdf) do  (%exepath% "%%v" -w  )
```

but it would not work.

Comment: It's exactly the same as your original code, **just with the `/r` removed**!

Comment: Your second command wouldn't work:; . `%f` isn't the same as.`%%v`. (And indeed it's the `/r` that does recursive through subfolders - see `for /?`)